# How to assign tags on an AWS API Gateway deployment stage using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-serverless

I am using Hashicorp Terraform to define an AWS API Gateway to hit a Lambda function. I have a requirement that I need to tag my AWS resources with a particular tag so that costs can be tracked. Terraform seems to allow this for most resources. However, when creating an API Gateway stage using [aws_api_gateway_deployment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_deployment.html) I do not have the option to specify tags.

I see that Terraform recently added the resource [aws_api_gateway_stage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_stage.html). This one does allow tags to be specified. But, **aws_api_gateway_stage** requires an **aws_api_gateway_deployment**. If I give them the same "stage_name" as so:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "PlayLambdaApiGatewayStage" {
  stage_name = "${environment}"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.PlayLambdaApiGateway.id}"
  deployment_id = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.PlayLambdaApiGatewayDeployment.id}"
  tags = {
    cost-allocation = "play-${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "PlayLambdaApiGatewayDeployment" {
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.PlayLambdaApiLambdaIntegration",
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.PlayLambdaApiLambdaIntegrationRoot"
  ]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.PlayLambdaApiGateway.id}"
  stage_name  = "${var.environment}"
}
```

Then they both resources try to create the stage and I get an error:

**aws_api_gateway_stage.PlayLambdaApiGatewayStage: Error creating API Gateway Stage: ConflictException: Stage already exists
    status code: 409, request id: f67a10c4-8aad-11e8-b486-c337ea2d214f**

Here it would seem that the **aws_api_gateway_deployment** already created the stage, so the **aws_api_gateway_stage** resource failed to create it also. If I add the stage to the deployment's "depends_on" so that the stage gets created first, it complains about there being a cycle between the two.

So, it seems like:

- **aws_api_gateway_stage** is only intended to add additional stages to a deployment, rather than creating a stage to use for the deployment
- **aws_api_gateway_deployment** does not allow tags to be specified when it creates the stage.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1153).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `stage_name` field in the **api_gateway_deployment** should actually be optional. There is a PR open to fix the fact that its not at the moment. A workaround is at the moment to set `stage_name` to an empty string like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "PlayLambdaApiGatewayDeployment" {
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.PlayLambdaApiLambdaIntegration",
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.PlayLambdaApiLambdaIntegrationRoot"
  ]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.PlayLambdaApiGateway.id}"
  stage_name  = ""
}
```

Like this there will be no additional stage created other than the one you specify in your **aws_api_gateway_stage** which you can set your tags for.